# ASP.NET Application pulling from multiple GAC DLL's of different versions

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, gac

So I have multiple versions of a library in our main web server's GAC, which are working fine with some of our applications, but is currently breaking with one. Here is a snippet of the error that I'm getting right now:

[image]

As you can see, it's saying that the library exists in two different locations, each of which are different versions of the DLL in the GAC. In my web.config file, I have the following line in the `<assemblies>` block:

```
<add assembly="IllinoisState.CAS.Coins, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=43b230099bff1b05"/>
```

So I'm not really understanding why I'm getting the error? I'm calling the DLL and specifying what version I want to use, but it's yelling at me because the library exists in two different locations? Doesn't really make too much sense to me.

Oh, and currently we're using Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4241 and ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4223.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Check if you happen to have same DLL in BIN. ASP.NET searches for the assembly DLL first in the private Bin directory for the application, and then in the system assembly cache.

Comment: @bdoshi - I can verify that the DLL is not in the bin/ folder.